# Execute SSH port forwarding along with the browser

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, port-forwarding

I've successfully set up dynamic port forwarding over SSH in Pale Moon and added the alias as `ssh-forward` in .bashrc.

Now I have to execute both `ssh-forward` and `palemoon` to access the Internet over this tunnel.

I actually want to combine those commands resulting in only having to execute palemoon, and editing the .desktop file for it so it executes both commands when clicking on it.

This would also involve running the `ssh-forward` in the background, thus creating a PID for it.

What would be the best way to set this up? I'm specifically looking for a fast end-solution in which I would only have to click the icon, or executing palemoon from the Terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

openSSH supports `LocalCommand`, which can be used for this, just other way round than you describe. You run `ssh-forward` and as soon as it will be connected, the browser will start. It can work like this:

```
ssh -NTf -D localhost:9999 -oPermitLocalCommand=yes -oLocalCommand=palemoon host
```

of course addjust the ports and host.

This can be also put into the `~/.ssh/config` to shorten the command itself:

```
Host proxy-host
  Hostname host
  User username
  PermitLocalCommand=yes
  LocalCommand=palemoon
  DynamicForward localhost:9999
  RequestTTY no
```

and then run just

```
ssh -Nf proxy-host
```

which will bring up the proxy and the browser. You can simply store this command in your "shortcut".

Comment: The -NTf parameters you described aren't in my command yet.
How do they influence the existing command, which has -C and -D already and what's those -NTf parameters?

Comment: They don't have to be there, but they are common in forwarding commands. I believe you will find their meaning in manual page.

Comment: Ignorant me completely forgot about the manpages for a second, I'll take a look at it :)